# Clear form on `mfp-close` in magnific popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, magnific-popup

I am trying to clear all the errors and make input values blank on closing of magnific popup.

I inspected the class of 'close' button and tried to fire `jquery` event but it is not working.

```
$("button.mfp-close").on('click',function(){
  console.log("Closed");
});
```

When i click on `mfp-close` then there is no log in console.

HTML snippet is:

```
    <div class="mfp-content"><div id="customdesign" class="white-popup mfp-with-anim">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 text-center"> 
        <h3>Upload Your Design</h3>
        <p><span class="success_sbmt" style="display:none;color:green">Congratulations! We have sent you the coupon code on your registered email id</span>
        </p><form novalidate="novalidate" class="form cmxform" id="customForm">
        <input name="leave" value="http://" type="hidden">
        <input name="isblank" value="" type="hidden">
        <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only">Name</label>
        <input aria-required="true" class="form-control" name="nam_cst" id="nam_cst" 
     placeholder="Enter Name.." required="" type="text">
        <span class="help-block" style="color:red"></span>
     </div>
    </form>
</div>
</div>
<button title="Close (Esc)" type="button" class="mfp- close">×</button>       
</div></div>
```

How can we handle this operation??

Comment: Without HTML code it's hard to guess, post your HTML code snippet

Comment: @Shehary .. i have added HTML Snippet also

Comment: I see you are using bootstrap framework, why not use bootstrap modal, why magnific popup and extra js library when you can achieve same with bootstrap modal

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you are using bootstrap framework, use bootstrap modal instead magnific popup, no need for extra js librabry, you can achieve same with bootstrap modal

in your HTML, button you have `class="mfp- close"` it should be `class="mfp-close"` as you are binding it like this `$("button.mfp-close")`

To reset form on pop-up close, you can achieve it with `$('form')[0].reset();`

Script

```
$("button.mfp-close").on('click',function(){
    alert("Closed");
    $('form')[0].reset();
});
```

HTML

```
<a class="popup-modal" href="#customdesign">Open modal</a>

<div class="mfp-content">
<div id="customdesign" class="white-popup-block mfp-hide">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 text-center"> 
        <h3>Upload Your Design</h3>
        <p>
            <span class="success_sbmt" style="display:none;color:green">Congratulations! We have sent you the coupon code on your registered email id</span>
        </p>
        <form novalidate="novalidate" class="form cmxform" id="customForm">
        <input name="leave" value="http://" type="hidden">
        <input name="isblank" value="" type="hidden">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only">Name</label>
                <input aria-required="true" class="form-control" name="nam_cst" id="nam_cst" placeholder="Enter Name.." required="" type="text">
                <span class="help-block" style="color:red"></span>
        </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<button title="Close (Esc)" type="button" class="mfp-close">×</button>       
</div>
</div>
```

[Working fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/m6s7mbvL/1/)

Comment: I am nt using bootstrap modal becausr thise r nt pretty enough.. so i switched to mfp.. secondly i ll try and let u knw